# Adding values in a dictionary with the same key

Tags: python, class, dictionary, key

I am working to import a text file into a dictionary. The file has student IDs and the number of credit hours they have taken to date. Once I create a class for the Students and open the dictionary I cannot figure out how to add the values together that share a similar key.

```py
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self, ID, hours):
        self.id = id
        self.hours = hours

        d = {}
        stud = open("students.txt", "r")
        for line in stud:
            line = line.strip()
            new_file = line.split(",")
            d[stud[0]] = Student(stud[0], stud[1])
```

now I am stuck?

Comment: do you want to add the hours? Or do you want to save multiple Student objects with the same ID?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I need to take each student ID and then add the total hours for each student if they appear more than once in my file (some do). I think someone helped answer my question already, although the hours aren't showing properly. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me now.

```
d = {}

class Student:
    def __init__(self, id, hours):
        self.id = id
        self.hours = hours

with open('filename.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        stu = (line.strip()).split(',')
        d[stu[0]] = Student(stu[0], stu[1])

print(d)
```

Comment: holy cow i think that actually works! How come with I print d the hours do not display though? Instead I get the student id and then "<_main__.Student object at 0x00000.......>,"

Comment: if you want to get the attributes of an object you use
**Student.__dict__**
but you don't really need a class here. you could just append the id and the hours to the dictionary as key and a value.
when you print an object it prints the memory location of it not its attributes.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on this, please? I created a class because I am also creating a function to do calculations on the hours. When I attempt to call my function I cannot see the hour totals and am getting the memory location. I tried to make tweaks to your code but what I've done is no longer combinging the same keys together! I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Will this help:

```
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self, ID, hours):
        self.id = id
        self.hours = hours

        d = {}
        with open("students.txt", "r") as stud:

            s = [l.strip().split(",") for l in stud.readlines()]

            if stud[0] not in d.keys(): # If the student is not yet in the dictionary
                d[stud[0]] = Student(stud[0], stud[1]) # Add the student
            else: # If already in
                d[stud[0]].hours += stud[1] # Add the hours to that student's hours
```